# Create sum / subtotal which related to dash_table.DataTable

Tags: python

How to create a sum/ subtotal row which related to dash_table.DataTable?

The sum/subtotal column may not a must to be include in the dash_table.DataTable, it can be an external column or row unless the figure is correct and can based on the filter in the dash_table.DataTable.

Create something like excel's subtotal.

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Looking solution for this matter.